# PHP Curl will only work if executed in CLI, not via the web

Tags: php, apache, curl, web

I'm a bit confused here. I have a file **provision_test.php** which when executed with **php provision_test.php** will run fine, execute curl, and get the page. But when executed from the web **http://example.com/provision_test.php** it fails to properly run. I am running Ubuntu Linux 12.04.1 server, x86_64.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated... and let me know if you need any extra information, I'd be glad to help you help me.

**EDIT 1**

**FILE: provision_test.php**

```
<?php

    $domain = "example.net";
    $password = "123";
    $serverip = "example.com:10000";

    $ch = curl_init();

    $userpwd = 'root:password';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://{$serverip}/virtual-server/remote.cgi?program=create-domain&domain={$domain}&pass={$password}&default-features");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $userpwd);

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

?>
```

*The php5-curl package is installed on the system. However I have not specifically enabled curl in the php.ini file. How would I go about doing this?*

I can verify that the php5-curl package was installed properly, however I cannot confirm that apache has enabled it. I know from executing it in the command line that curl works.

Additionally, I do not have selinux or something like that on my server.

I'll be running the script again with PHP errors on to see if I find anything tomorrow.

Comment: Please post a relevant code sample from `provision_test.php` (or the whole thing if it's not very long)

Comment: I suppose you have enabled curl in apache, in the php.ini located commonly in `/etc/php5/apache/php.ini`. Also, I suppose, you already did `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

Comment: "fails to properly run" --- isn't a technical issue explanation

Comment: extra info would include what you've done to debug this yourself. we're here to help, but you do have to do SOME work yourself. e.g. verify that the web-based PHP has curl installed properly. did you check for error conditions? maybe a webserver security system (selinux, suhosin, etc...) is blocking the request. these are all things we can not possibly help you at all with, because you've provided absolutely no useful details.

Comment: Check out what I added.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had the same issue as described.
From CLI the script works fine, from the browser it ends up with error 7

Please enable Verbose mode using:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
```

Run the script from CLI
If you have the same problem as I did, it's because of proxy and maybe authentication as well, so you will have to add the following options to your curl script

```
$proxy = 'url or ip';
$proxy_port = 8080;
$proxy_username = 'username';
$proxy_password = 'password';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxy_username.':'.$proxy_password);
```

This saved the last 30minutes of my working day ;-D

Hopefully this will be helpfull for you.

Comment: If this is supposed to be an answer it is very confusing. I am proposing some updates to it to help make sense of it.

Comment: I just now see what you tried to tell me Mike, after I adjusted my post  this is my first post in stack and I'm trying to find my way in it as well. My apologies!

Comment: No worries. Everyone has to learn. This looks much better than what you had here to begin with.